# can someone pinpoint the difference between "proper" and "properly" in these sentences?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

I came across the thought of different meaning that can be attributed to sentences if you place adjectives in different positions in it.

So my question is do these sentences really differ somehow?

1. "The plane did not land on the proper runway"
2. "The plane did not land on the runway proper"
3. "The plane did not land on the runway properly"

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence says the plane landed on the wrong runway.

The second says it chose the right runway but did not quite get it right - perhaps it used what on a highway would be the shoulder.

The third includes the second as a special case. Perhaps the plane landed in the center of the runway but too fast. Here the adverb  "properly" modifies "land" and might have been placed right after "land".

Answer (score 0):

*Proper* is an adjective, *properly* is an adverb.

(1) means that the plane landed on the wrong runway.

(2) is bad English because it uses an adjective where an adverb is required.

(3) means that the plane landed on the runway in the wrong way.

Comment: As I think Ethan Bolker is alluding to, #2 could be correct if you think of it as "on the runway *proper*", i.e. "on the runway itself exactly", but I doubt that's what the OP was thinking of.

Comment: @stangdon - Yes, I was just contemplating making an edit to that effect.

Comment: @stangdon I too doubt that's what the OP was thinking, but it is proper usage.

Comment: as I was  thinking before asking the question that  the number 2 sentence means what @than Bolker said in his answer. I just wanted to confirm. So in this case number 3 sentence equals number 2 in sense, right?

Comment: the sentence "The plane did not land on the runway proper" is not "a cloed sentence" and leaves room to be added more words to complet it ideia so it could go like: "The plane did not land on the runway proper in landing parameters". sentence number one is a "closed sentence" where its idea is fully conveyned

Comment: @henrykearaudjo I'm not sure what you mean by "a closed sentence", but #2 does not need any more words and actually sounds worse if you try to add more words.  "land on the runway proper" does not mean "land on the runway correctly", it means "land on the runway, as we usually define *runway*."

Comment: noun + proper means: noun itself.

Comment: @stangdon, what you mean by "land on the runway proper" does not mean "land on the runway correctly"??? as  Ethan Bolker said: "The second says it chose the right runway but did not quite get it right - perhaps it used what on a highway would be the shoulder." if "land on the runway proper" does not means ""land on the runway correctly" then what does that means?

Comment: @tangdon, what I meant by "closed sentence" is a sentence that has enough words to convey an idea, but I'm not sure if that terminology is correct

Comment: Henryke, _The runway proper_ means _the runway itself, in the proper meaning of the word_. That's why Ethan suggested that (2) could mean that the plane landed on the edge of the runway (what we call the [hard] shoulder on a motorway). The sentence is incorrect if you just meant _proper_ as a synonym of _properly_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, cool I really get it now